# How to split content with jquery after certain amount of divs

Tags: jquery, forms, parent-child

I have a form like this:

```
<div class="content">
  <form>
    <div class="item">
      blablaform stuf
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      blablaform stuf
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      blablaform stuf
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      blablaform stuf
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Now I want to wrap a few of the item divs inside form. Basically like this:

```
<div class="content">
  <form>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="item">
        blablaform stuf
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        blablaform stuf
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="item">
        blablaform stuf
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        blablaform stuf
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

How can I do it with jQuery? `append()`? `:nth-child` or how?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry @Yi Jiang, think we had an edit-clash =/ @mikeyy, I'd suggest learning how forms work. Things like `fieldset`, for example.

Comment: @David Ah, no it's okay, you're edit was better than mine anyway. As long as five people doesn't jump in and turn this into CW within a minute it's fine :)

Answer (score 3):

Something like this would work:

```
var elems = $(".content div.item");
for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i+=2) {
  elems.slice(i, i+2).wrapAll("<div class='wrapper'></div>");
}
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/5YP2r/), what this does is grab all the `.item` `<div>` elements in there, and every pair of 2 wraps them, if there are any left over (a last single one) it'll be wrapped by itself.

---

Or, let's make it reusable, as a plugin:

```
jQuery.fn.wrapSet = function (interval, wrapElem) {
  for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i+=interval) {
    this.slice(i, i+interval).wrapAll(wrapElem);
  }
  return this;
};
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
$(".content div.item").wrapSet(2, "<div class='wrapper'></div>");​
```

[You can give that version a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/5YP2r/1/).

Comment: I'm curious, just how awesome were you *before* JavaScript? =)

Comment: @David - I spend most of my day in C#/Oracle actually, JavaScript is just a hobby :)